# Configured storage parameter to be persistent in journald.conf

Tags: logging, kernel

Even after configuring **storage=persistent** in **journald.conf** configuration file under **/etc/systemd**, journal directory (log) is getting created/stored under **/run/log/journal** instead of **/var/log/journal**. Please let me know what are other configurations that have to be taken care of. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess when systemd-journald is starting, it tries to creates /var/log/journal. It will fail because of the following:
- in the rfs, /var/log is a symlink which points to /var/volatile/log
- /var/volatile will be mounted as tmpfs (memory device) during startup
- after mounting, /var/volatile/log and several other directories are created during startup as well at this point, /var/volatile/log exists so that the symlink /var/log appears as an actual directory
- The problem now is that systemd-journald is started before the volatile file system is set up
- The steps mentioned above are not done when systemd-journald is starting up
- As a result, /var/log looks not like a directory but like a symlink that points to nothing
- because of this, systemd cannot create the directory /var/log/journald and hence is not persistently storing the journal there. Ok to achieve this, you must remove the symlink /var/log and create a directory /var/log in the rfs. Now, data should be stored persistently in this directory either on sd card or on the nfs folder depending on how you are booting the platform.